# Is it possible to have an in-browser debugger?

Tags: javascript

Is it presently possible to programatically debug Javascript from within a browser window? I wish to be able to breakpoint/inspect Javascript from an in-browser window panel.

EDIT:

I should have been more specific: I'm loogking for an api to be used from within the page context, i.e. JS code in browser can add it's own breakpoints.

Comment: Have a look at http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: Firebug extension for Firefox, Developer Tools built-in to Chrome & Safari, IE8+ developer console - press F12.

Comment: A google search for "browser javascript debugger" might be a good idea ...

Comment: @Pointy A google search for 3 of the hottest programming keywords? YAH! Great idea! Never thought of it!

Comment: Well, had you done that, crazy as it may seem, you'd have seen Firebug as one of the first results (if not the first). Had you then looked into Firebug, you could have read about its "console" API, that provides all sorts of ways to trace execution. That, combined with the native `debugger;` statement (which is as close to a "breakpoint" as I can imagine), is probably as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Also you might get a better answer if you could describe some *other* programming environment that has facilities similar to what you'd like for JavaScript.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing me at the Console API. I did not see it in all the time i have been using firebug.

Comment: Also, languages that have intuitive debug interfaces: Python. Simply fantastic debugging support

Comment: Console API is good for profiling but provides no low level hooks to get in to the debugging envionment :(

Answer (score 9):

It's already built-in in Chrome and Safari and, to an extent, in Firefox. There exists multiple plugins for this. Look at **Firebug** for Firefox, and **F12 Developer Tools** for IE.

Comment: Built in to Opera as well (Dragonfly)

Comment: very useful tool to work on JS that runs in chrome on firefox called chromebug, i love this tool saved me weeks of debugging.

Comment: I'm looking for an API that can be used from within the page context.

Comment: @Thomas have you ever heard of the `debugger;` statement?

Comment: @Pointy no i have not, however all that does is break to the builtin debugger, which is not what i want.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize your browser's developer tools:
Use browser-specific developer tools, which allow you to identify runt-time errors, set up breakpoints, and run performance diagnostics.  To make debugging much easier, don’t minify the JavaScript during development deployment.

In IE:  IE Developer Tools

Or install the Google Chrome Frame which allows IE to process JavaScript with Google Chrome’s V8 engine and allows the user to debug with the Chrome Developer Tools

In FF:  Firebug extension

In Chrome:  Chrome Developer Tools

Use a static code checker, like JSLint, to verify that JavaScript code complies with generally accepted coding rules.

Use JsFiddle to easily test and improve JavaScript/jQuery functions (http://jsfiddle.net/)
This has a JSLint option for parsing the JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox, try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

If you're using Chrome, it has an in-built debugger.

For IE there's something called [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) and F12 Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

just go for firebug.

http://getfirebug.com

you can also have breakpoints

http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome -> Right Click -> Inspect Element

or

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

F12 in almost any modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are possiblities to do that.

For Chrome for example you can use the 
the [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html) extension to attach your own debugger-implementation to a website, that runs in another tab/window. Once you are attached, you control the debugger vie a JSON based [remote debugging protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/index). The biggest problem I would say is, that you have to pipe all your communication through an HTML-Element. This is the case because the extension can only communicate with a content script and the content script can only access DOM-specified attributes.

John Bartons chrome extension [crx2app](https://github.com/johnjbarton/crx2app) tries to simplify the access to the extension API. I don't know how much it actually supports, but it might also be helpful for developing a Debugger that runs from within the browser itself.

As far as I know Firefox also provides access to its internal JavaScript-Engine Spidermonkey and by extension to its [debugging mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Guide). But that might in fact collide with a FireBug plug-in, because you can usually only attach one listener to the Debugger. But with the recent release of the new Firefox [built-in JavaScript-Debugger](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/debugger-responsive-design-view-and-more-in-firefox-aurora-15/), which provides remote-access, this might be no longer a problem.